# Pyjnius looking for libjvm.so in wrong folder - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, java, pyjnius

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu (16.04, armhf) and am trying to use pytimeextractor which requires both cython and pyjnius to enable the Java/Python interaction, but am running into the following error with pyjnius:

`SystemError: Error calling dlopen(b'/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so': b'/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'`

I was initially having issues with setting JAVA_HOME (getting a KeyError), which lead me to purge existing Java installations such as the folder referenced in the SystemError above: "*/jdk1.8.0-openjdk-armhf/..."

After reinstalling Java and setting JAVA_HOME in etc/environment, then uninstalling and reinstalling pyjnius, it is still pointing to this old, now non-existent Java installation... rather than the JAVA_HOME now set (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-armhf) and I have not the slightest idea why.

Could someone please help point me in the right direction of resolving this issue? I feel out of my depth with the extent of Ubuntu knowledge required to accurately diagnose the errors in front of me and swiftly resolve them. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue. As far as I can tell, I had set the JAVA_HOME to point at the correct installation of Java but needed to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.